# Webscraping different URLs - limit

Tags: python, pandas, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have coded a web scraper for auto trader but for some reason when iterating through urls I can only ever get a maximum length of 1300 for my dataframe. There are 13 results per page so is there some sort of significance about a limit of 100 or am I just doing something wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated :)
I've attached my code below

```
# Import required libraries
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

# List of urls
path = 'https://www.autotrader.co.uk/car-search?advertClassification=standard&postcode=RH104JJ&make=&price-from=500&price-to=100000&onesearchad=Used&onesearchad=Nearly%20New&onesearchad=New&advertising-location=at_cars&is-quick-search=TRUE&page='
urls = []
for i in range(1,500):
    url = path + str(i)
    urls.append(url)

# Lists to store the scraped data in
makes = []
prices = []
ratings = []
dates = []
types = []
miles = []
litres = []
bhps = []
transmissions = []
fuels = []
owners = []

attributes = [makes, ratings, dates, types, miles, litres, bhps, transmissions, fuels, owners]
    
# Iterate through urls
sum = 0
for url in urls:
    sum += 1
    if sum%10 == 0:
        print(sum)
    
    # Attempt to connect to the url
    try:
        response = get(url)
    except:
        print('oops')
    html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

    # Get a list of individual cars and iterate through it
    car_containers = html_soup.find_all('li', class_ = 'search-page__result')
        
    for container in car_containers:
        try:
            container.find("div", {"class": "js-tooltip"}).find("div", {"class": "pi-indicator js-tooltip-trigger"}).text
            rating = container.find("div", {"class": "js-tooltip"}).find("div", {"class": "pi-indicator js-tooltip-trigger"}).text.strip()
        except:
            rating = ''
        ratings.append(rating)
        
        make = container.h2.text.strip().title().split(' ')[0]
        makes.append(make)

        price = container.find("div", {"class": "vehicle-price"}).text[1:]
        prices.append(price)

        specs = container.find("ul", {"class": "listing-key-specs"}).find_all("li", recursive=True)

        for spec in specs:
            
            if spec.text.split(' ')[0].isdigit() and len(spec.text.split(' ')[0]) == 4:
                date = spec.text.split(' ')[0]
                dates.append(date)

            if 'mile' in str(spec):
                mile = spec.text.split(' ')[0]
                miles.append(mile)

            if 'l' in str(spec).lower() and str(spec.text)[:-1].replace('.', '').isnumeric() and not spec.text.split(' ')[0].isdigit():
                litre = spec.text[:-1]
                litres.append(litre)

            if any(x in str(spec).lower() for x in ['automatic', 'manual']):
                transmission = spec.text
                transmissions.append(transmission)

            if any(x in str(spec).lower() for x in ['bhp', 'ps']):
                bhp = spec.text
                bhps.append(bhp)

            if any(x in str(spec).lower() for x in ['petrol', 'diesel']):
                fuel = spec.text
                fuels.append(fuel)
                
            if 'owner' in str(spec):
                owner = spec.text
                owners.append(owner.split(' ')[0])
            
        
            typelist = ['hatchback', 'saloon', 'convertible', 'coupe', 'suv', 'mpv', 'estate', 'limousine',
                        'pickup']
            if any(x in str(spec).lower() for x in typelist):
                typ = spec.text
                types.append(typ)
            
        
        # Filling in empty spaces
        for attribute in attributes:
            if len(attribute) < len(prices):
                attribute.append('')
                    

# Creating a dataframe from the lists
df = ({'makes': makes,
       'Price': prices,
        'Rating': ratings,
        'Year': dates,
        'Type': types,
        'Miles': miles,
        'Litres': litres,
        'BHP': bhps,
        'Transmission': transmissions,
        'Fuel': fuels,
        'Owners': owners
})
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

Comment: There's results only till page 100, pages 101 onwards don't contain any, for example `https://www.autotrader.co.uk/car-search?sort=relevance&postcode=RH104JJ&radius=1500&price-from=500&price-to=100000&page=101`

Comment: Oh wow, this is definitely a facepalm moment! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just use a url shortener if the length of the url is too long

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Why would this solve the issue of only being able to collect data from 100 webpages?

Comment: Clarification with an example or link to documentation would be helpful here in explaining how this might solve the issue.